# how to use mixins with lodash and typescript with chaining support

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, mixins, chaining

I'm having trouble using Lodash with typescript when I'm trying to extend lodash with my custom mixins.

**My unsuccessful attempt:**

Lets say I add a new function to lodash using mixins as follows:

```
//lodashMixins.ts

import * as _ from "lodash";

_.mixin({
  swap
});

function swap(array: Array<any>, index1: number, index2: number) {
    let temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
    return array;
}
```

The function `swap` is not available on `_` if I `import _ from "lodash";` in other files.

**Partially successful attempt:**

Then I looked for [help, and people suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725869/how-to-use-lodash-mixin-in-typescript) to `extend` `_.LoDashStatic` and then export the `_` as the new extended `interface`.

Then I did following:

```
//lodashMixins.ts

import * as _ from "lodash";

interface LodashExtended extends _.LoDashStatic {
  swap(array: Array<any>, index1: number, index2: number): Array<any>;
}

_.mixin({
  swap
});

function swap(array: Array<any>, index1: number, index2: number) {
    let temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
    return array;
}

export default _ as LodashExtended;
```

And using the new *mixed-in* as following:

```
//otherFile.ts

import _ from "./lodashMixins";

function someFn(){
    var array = [1,2,3,4]
    _.swap(array, 1, 2);
}
```

Now this works, but **there are two issues**:

1. First that the new `swap` function is not working with lodash's chained syntax (neither with explicit chaining nor with implicit chaining).

which means, that typescript gets angry if I do any of the following:

```
//otherFile.ts

import _ from "./lodashMixins";

function someFn(){
    var cantDothis = _.chain([1,2,3,4]).map(x=>x*x).swap(1,2).value();
    //[ts] Property 'swap' does not exist on type 'LoDashExplicitWrapper<number[]>'.

    var neitherThis = _([1,2,3,4]).map(x=>x*x).swap(1,2).value();
    //[ts] Property 'swap' does not exist on type 'LoDashImplicitWrapper<number[]>'.
}
```

2. Second that I have to do this ***ugly*** `import _ from "./lodashMixins";` instead of standard `import _ from "lodash";`.

**Someone please come up with an elegant solution that provides typescript type support while chaining without any code smell or ugliness..
Thanks. :)**

May be [John-David Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166625/john-david-dalton) can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for module augmentation. You can extend interfaces in existing modules by redefining them and adding extra methods. In this case you should augment `LoDashStatic` for static usage and `LoDashExplicitWrapper` for chain usage. When you use the module, you can first import `lodash` and then import the module containing `swap` for its side effects (the side effect of adding the method to `lodash`)

```
// swap.ts
import * as _ from "lodash";


declare module "lodash" {
    interface LoDashStatic {
        swap<TValue>(array: Array<TValue>, index1: number, index2: number): TValue[];
    }
    interface LoDashExplicitWrapper<TValue> {
        swap(index1: number, index2: number): LoDashExplicitWrapper<TValue>;
    }
}

_.mixin({
    swap
});

function swap(array: Array<any>, index1: number, index2: number) {
    let temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
    return array;
}

//usage 
import * as _ from "lodash";
import "./swap"


console.log(_.chain([1,2,3,4]).map(x=>x*x).swap(1,2).map(x=> x * 2).value());

var array = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(  _.swap(array, 1, 2));
```

You can read more about module augmentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks you very much. :)

Comment: Very helpful! I had also to add the interface `LoDashImplicitWrapper` for TS to type correctly `_([1, 2, 3]).swap(0, 2).value()`. TS v3.2.2, Lodash v4.17.11.